# My URL's query string does not work

Tags: php, webmatrix-2

Currently I'm using web matrix2 to build my php application.
I was testing passing the query string to another php using GET

Scenario 1:
I have index.php and test.php 
in index.php: I have a php statement `include("/test.php");` 
 
in test.php: i only have 2 statements `echo "hi"; and echo $_GET["msg"];`
when I run it, nothing appear in my browser

When I get rid of the `echo $_GET["msg"];`, it works again.

Scenario 2:
I have index.php and test.php 
in index.php: I have a php statement `include("/test.php?msg=hihihi")`; 
in test.php: i only have 2 statements `echo "hi"; and echo $_GET["msg"]`;
when I run it, nothing appear in my browser

Even I tried to type the Url `http://localhost:port/test.php?msg=hihihi`, nothing appear as well..~

Then I tried to test it using a link

```
<a href="http://localhost:62878/menu/AddCat.php?msg=hihihi">link</a>
```

still nothing was displayed at AddCat.php page.

I have tried it in EasyPhp...~ 
The error showed in EasyPHP is 

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'test.php?msg=hihi' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\testing\index.php on line 2

 if I put the query string together with the url in the php include statement.

I'm not sure how why my code didn't work previously, but now fix.

thanks.

Comment: My guess is that the test.php cannot be found because `/` in PHP is different from `/` in HTML. You should enable error reporting to be sure.

Comment: better you put all the file contents "as it is" here.

Comment: At the moment you are trying to include data by making an HTTP request to a file and passing data to it in a query string. Don't. Rewrite the page as a function, then include the file containing the function, then call the function with the data you want to pass as an argument.

Comment: @Quentin : do mind to tell me why it is not encourage to perform http request to a file while passing data along in the query string?
Is it possible like passing along a security token as well?

Comment: It's inefficient and hard to debug

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the path that you see in the browser URI with the filepath on the server. The `include()` statement refers to the filesystem on the server and `/test.php` would be a document right at the top of the filesystem (somewhere you're very unlikely to be writing to).

Assuming `test.php` is in the same directory as the script you're trying to include it from you can simply use `include("test.php")`

If there's a runtime/syntax error then PHP will log this in the Apache error log, be sure to take a look at it.

Comment: Indeed both are in the same directory.
I also have tested include("test.php?msg=hihihi"); still nothing appear.
I'm using web matrix 2, so how to check in web matrix 2 for the log file you mentioned?

Comment: How are you going to include a file with arguments? include is like if you copied and pasted the content of the file where you write it, not as if you called it!

Answer (score -1):

Please run

```
index.php?msg=hihihi
```

it will show you result